# Media query using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, media

I am using the same view page (with CSS) in 3 different areas where resolutions are different. My problem is that I want some block of media query at some condition only.

Like:

```
if( a == 20)
{
@media (max-width : 900px) and (min-width :500px){
// some code 
}
}
if( a == 40)
{
@media (max-width : 900px) and (min-width :500px){
// some code 
}
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the "some condition" you speak of? Can this not be handled on the server side, allowing you to only load relevant CSS files when necessary?

Comment: It may be more appropriate to define a class in the elements for each condition, and applying the CSS for each class.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly i have only one css but using that view page in different resolutions of site

Comment: @VítorMarques yeah! it work's but its very tough for me right now due to large number of elements so i m trying for alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Crossfire's suggestion is probably the best. Just add a class to your HTML tag based on the conditions.

If you're looking for a JS only solution, you can use `window.matchMedia`

For instance:

```
 if( a == 20)
 {
     window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width:500px)') 
     {
     // some code 
     }
 }
 if( a == 40)
 {
     window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width:500px)')
     {
     // some code 
     }
 }
```

This is basically a media query in JS and it also pretty much works the same. Please note that this solution is not supported in IE9 or lower.

Edit: here's a solution that also works in IE9 or lower. What this does is simply call the function on window resize or load. Then you can add in conditions as you wish. You should be able to work with this.

```
  $(function() {

      window.responsive = function responsive() {
         //get the width of the window
         var width = $(window).width();

         if (width > 500 && width < 900) {
                //width is larger than 500px and smaller than 900px
                $('div').addClass('md-screen');
         }
       }

  });
  //Call the function on load and resize
  $(window).on('ready load resize orientationchange',function(){responsive();});
```

Comment: I edited my answer with a solution that will also work in IE9 and lower. Hope this helps.

Comment: this will works but i need to and classes for each and ever element which i want to resize

Comment: Nope. You can just add a class to the parent or the html and then address the elements like `html.added-class .regularclass {/*add width specific styles here*/}` when the class on the parent/html is not active all your styles will be as normal.

Comment: @ Anwardo, After 5 years, your code is still working well!  I really like a way you catch windown's width, but I don't know what is "window.responsive = function responsive()" about?  Can you please explain?

Comment: @abcidd, thanks for your comment! That statement is just assigning a (named) function as a global variable (the `window` scope). The fact that the function is named doesn't really serve any purpose in this code, it could have been an anonymous function as well. Looking at the code now I would certainly change a few things. Mostly there is no need to assign the width checking function to the global scope. Both the function and the event handler could have simply be scoped to the `$(function() {});`.